# Inserting into a MongoDB that doesn't exist yet

Tags: mongodb

I am very new to mongoDB but so far enjoying it. I have a question that may be obvious to someone but I am having a hard time finding it in the search. I'll walk you through my steps and then as the question. If you first type:

```
show dbs
```

And it prints your dbs, my results:

```
local  0.000GB
test   0.000GB
```

So now I want to insert data into a db, I go and use the following command to insert it into a db that technically doesn't exist:

```
db.stores.insert({ _id: 1, name: "Java Hut", description: "Coffee and cakes" })
```

When I do show dbs again it doesn't show up there but I can do db.stores.count() function and it returns a result. I can also do searches or anything I want to stores without an issue. **Have I now created a new db?** This is a theoretical question, I'm pretty sure you would never normally do this. Also, I am using the command line for all of this.

Comment: you mean to say where it is located in storage?

Comment: I mean - Have I now created a new db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, when you open the mongo shell you will be connected to the `test` database.

```
db.stores.insert({ _id: 1, name: "Java Hut", description: "Coffee and cakes" })
```

The above query inserts a document into the `stores` collection of the `test` db. stores is a collection and not a database. If `stores` does not exist already, it is created.

```
use mydb;
```

The above statement will connect the mongo shell to the `mydb`. (Creates the db, if not already there.) You can then execute the queries on the collections in that database.

Comment: I think I wasn't properly understanding the concept of when you type db.nameOfCollection.insert() you are inserting into a collection which is in a database that you are using. And technically the data you are inserting is a document? Full of objects?

Database >Collection>Document>Object?

Comment: Yes. It is called a (json) document. Documents go into Collections; Collections go into Databases.